# Can I destroy a flash object created with SWFObject?

Tags: flash, swfobject

I am using YUI's Dialog control to show a Flash movie on my site in a popup.

I am creating the Flash control using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). This creates a [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) instance for my video.

I was quite surprised to see no easy way to destroy the movie in the [SWF Object FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/faq). When the YUI panel destroys itself it leaves an orphaned video playing.

What is the best way to destory a SWF control that was created with SWFObject, or is there no good way and I ought to just hide it instead and call 'stop()' ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

swfobject.removeSWF("myVideoPlayer");

--

**Edit**: this kills off the original `<DIV>` that you used to create the swfobject in the first place.

So if you need to recreate the Flash again you'll need to insert a new placeholder `<DIV>`.

```
<!-- you'll need to wrap the 'myVideoPlayer' DIV in another DIV -->
<div id="videoPlayerWrapper">
   <div id="myVideoPlayer"/>
   <a href="#" class="close">Close Player</a>
</div>

swfobject.removeSWF("myVideoPlayer");
$('#videoPlayerWrapper').prepend("<div id='myVideoPlayer'></div>");
```